# Bash Script: copy directory to external drive - how to navigate directories?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have JUST started looking into the world of scripting, specifically with with bash, and am trying to write a simple script to copy the contents of a folder (that contains sub-folders) to a back-up location on an external flash drive (trying to back-up Thunderbird's data).  I've looked at a couple of tutorials and what I'm running into are issues with how to navigate to parent directories within the script. The folder I want to copy exists in the directory 1 above where my script file lies.  To get to the hard drive I've got to back-up through two parent directories...  Here's what I've created (I'm running ubuntu 12.04):

```
#! /bin/bash

#this attepmts to copy the profile folder for Thunderbird to the backup drive
echo "...attempting to copy Thunderbird Profile to back-up drive (My Passport)"

#attempt to backup two directories to where media folder (and therefore My Passport is located)
parent=$(dirname $PWD)
grandparent=$(dirname $parent)
greatgrand=$(dirname $grandparent)

#show what directories the variables are set to
echo "...parent: $parent"
echo "...grandparent: $grandparent"
echo "...greatgrand: $greatgrand"

echo "...copying..."

#FIRST SUBSHELL 
#create a subshell and cd to directory to copy && tar directory
#tar: -c = create tarball, -f = tells it what to create " - " = is the unix convention for stdout (this goes with the -f) " . " = means the whole directory.  I the end this first subshell is creating a tarball and dumping it in stdout
# | = pipe
#SECOND SUBSHELL

(cd /mcp/.thunderbird/lOdhn9gd.default && tar -cf - .) | (cd $greatgrand/media/My Passport/Gmail_to_Thunderbird_Backup && tar -xpf -)
```

When I run this I get:

```
mcp@mcp-Satellite-A135:~/BashScriptPractice$ ./thunderProfileBU.sh
...attempting to copy Thunderbird Profile to back-up drive (My Passport)
...parent: /home/mcp
...grandparent: /home
...greatgrand: /
...copying...
./thunderProfileBU.sh: line 23: cd: //media/My: No such file or directory
./thunderProfileBU.sh: line 23: cd: /mcp/.thunderbird/lOdhn9gd.default: No such file or directory
```

I should be starting in the directory "/mcp".  I'm guessing I don't need it in the first sub-script (the last line) above but when I tried to just use "cd /.thunderbird/lOdhn9g..." I was still getting the error.  For the second sub-script I'm not sure exactly what is happening.  Am I just misunderstanding the folder navigation syntax?

Also, this is a side question but is scripting in this manner something a software developer should know how to do or is this kind of thing more reserved for system admins?  I haven't taken any scripting classes or do I know of any offered through my university however I find it interesting and can see how it could be pretty useful...  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `rsync`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with rsync. Is that a bash utility?  EDIT: Just looked it up.  Very interesting.  I'd be interesting in implementing that through a script as well although I feel I might still have issues navigating the different directories...

Comment: You could put `set -x` at the top of your script, it will print out each command as it runs, expanded, and can be a great help when debugging. Take it out when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `dirname` to get the parent of each directory, you could use `..`, where `$greatgrand` is simply `../../..`.

Now relying on parent directories in a script is often a bad idea because you have to garantee that they exist.

There's two places where your script fails:

```
./thunderProfileBU.sh: line 23: cd: //media/My: No such file or directory
```

You should protect the directory name since it contains spaces, and spaces are an argument separator.

```
./thunderProfileBU.sh: line 23: cd: /mcp/.thunderbird/lOdhn9gd.default: No such file or directory
```

The directory you want to copy doen't exist. I'm guessing you want `~mcp` instead, or `/home/mcp`.

If what you want is to backup your thunderbird preferences to an external drive, you should use `rsync`:

```
# Make sure directory exists
mkdir -p "/media/My Passport/Gmail_to_Thunderbird_Backup"
# Copy the contents recursively
rsync -av "~/.thunderbird/lOdhn9gd.default/" "/media/My Passport/Gmail_to_Thunderbird_Backup"
```

Comment: Thanks for your time on that.  All very helpful.  I'm going to look into rsync more...and exactly what the ~ does...

Comment: `~` stands for your home directory, as returned by the `$HOME` environment variable. To access any user's home directory, use the user's name, such as `~mcp` or `~root`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,  I would recommend using `cp -r` instead of the more complicated tar pipeline, which is only really useful if you're copying on a network.

Second, there are two issues with your script: The source directory you specified is `/mcp` and not `/home/mcp` and thus could not be found. The second issue is that the target directory you specified has a space in it. That space must be escaped by either using a backslash (`\`) before the space, or surrounding the entire directory with quotes:

```
"$greatgrand/media/My Passport/Gmail_to_Thunderbird_Backup"
```

I am not sure why you are using a relative path ("greatgrand"). It seems you would be better off using an absolute path, by simply starting with `/`. If you really want to refer to the greatgrand directory, use `../../../`. Each `../` goes up one level.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I was using the tar pipeline basically because I found a tutorial on it and it seemed interesting.  Originally I started off with "cp".  Can't believe I missed the /mcp!  Also, I didn't realize I needed quotes or a backslash for that space.  Great information.  Thanks.